# Two applications within one server block

Tags: nginx

I'm not sure if this is possible or not, but the goal is to serve two applications within one server block. The primary application is NodeJS, but I would like to have a "/blog" that would point to a Wordpress install on the server. I am currently able to serve the blog on a subdomain.

The nginx config currently looks like this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on;
    root /var/www/html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    server_name blog.example.com;
    location / {
      try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }  

    location ~ \.php$ {
      include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
      fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }
}
server {
    listen 443 ssl default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
    include snippets/xyz.conf;
    include snippets/zyx.conf;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/;
        proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

Is there a way for me to serve the blog to "/blog" inside of the second server block in a similar fashion as the first?

Comment: Hint: location block in the server block.

Comment: I wasn't sure if it was possible, but I have figured that much assuming it was. I tried multiple configuration with that, but nothing was working. Any suggestions?

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44302541/nginx-configuration-for-wordpress-in-subdirectory-of-rails-app-in-same-server/44305655#44305655). Also, you will need to [change the WordPress site URL](https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL).

Comment: Thank you @RichardSmith. That helped me tremendously. I was able to get it going with that. Appreciate your help.