# nginx configuration to have different root from location

Tags: nginx, configuration

I'm trying to configure nginx in order to have different projects via different URL.
Let me explain.
You visit `http://localhost/test1` and nginx ask PHP to process the file in `/var/www/test-1/index.php`
You visit `http://localhost/test2`and nginx ask PHP to process the file in `/var/www/test-2/index.php`

The problem is : I only have 404 errors. Here is my nginx config :

```
server {
listen 80;
listen [::]:80;
root /var/www;
index  index.php index.html index.htm;
server_name  192.168.15.92;

location /test1 {
    alias /var/www/test-2;
}

location /test2 {
    alias /var/www/test-2;
}


location ~ \.php$ {
       include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
#       # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
       fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
}
}
```

I'm running debian 9.

Hope someone can help me :)

Comment: You need a nested `location ~ \.php$` block within each aliased `location`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44302541/nginx-configuration-for-wordpress-in-subdirectory-of-rails-app-in-same-server/44305655#44305655) for inspiration.

Comment: I tried and now I have a page saying "File not found." instead of a 404.

Comment: @Vestibule to remove "File not found" message for this setting you need add `fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;` on the block the `~ \.php$ {}`